# How to create a reusable activity for this!

Tags: android, android-activity

I want a reusable activity with only 3 buttons

[EDIT]
[DELETE]
 [SHARE]

just like a controller, in MVC design. hehe

Different activities with listviews, will access this through their listview_items, how can I do that implementation. :( any simple and great tutorials/suggestion would be greatly appreciated!:))

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are trying to acomplish something similar to a MVC CRUD pattern here?

A suggestions could be to set up a intentfilter in the manifest for each "datatype" in your listviews. The Intentfilters are associated with a specialized activity thats coded to handle the specific behaviour for the data type.

From a code perspective these activities could have a common super/abstract activity class activity that contains the common behaviour /UI /Event handlers etc.

The extending subclasses could then override/implement a specific onDelete, onEdit, onShare if that datatype's behaviour differs from the default behaviour.

Not sure I'm making sense here?